How can you make a Custom Ellipse Tool through Geometry Nodes?
I have been working on this side project on and off for a few months now and I have finally come across a need for your assistance.
I want to create a custom Ellipse Tool Modifier for use in edit mode with Geometry Nodes. Here are my conditions for the Modifier,

Every independent first point added will be the Center
Every second point connected to the first point will be the edge of a circle (Radius)
Every third point connected to the second point will be the scale perpendicular to the direction of the first point (Second Radius)


Here, is my attempt.

My Node Group used

Bugs
Disappearing Radius 2.
Every time a new circle is added, the second radius disappears for one of my ellipses. There is something affecting the second radii of my ellipses. I honestly don't know what it is.

Inconsistent Order of Points.
Some new circles/ellipses added are inconsistent to the order of points already created. The first point is not the center of the shape. How do I keep the order of points consistent when I add them?

I am somewhat aware that whenever a new point is added through edit mode, its index may become the largest integer or the smallest, 0 (all existing indices +1). However, I'm curious if anyone has some workarounds to fix these bugs. Perhaps someone has a better node tree?

Blender 4.3.0


…whenever a new point is added… its index may become the largest integer or the smallest, 0 (all existing indices +1)…

This is not true… I never experienced indices being shuffled upon adding another… Always the next available (number equal to total before addition) index is given to a new vertex… Upon removing a vertex or more, all indices are shifted to the left in order…
When converting mesh to curve, indices can be changed, according to this…
Blender 4.0 Manual: Geometry Nodes: Inspection: Geometry Randomization
However based on my testing, only the order of splines is random, the order of points within the splines remains… So the first vertex of the mesh island becomes the first point of the curve…
The algorithm then becomes…

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror


I think relying on mesh elements indices is not recommended because they can be invalidated and shuffled in some cases (UNDO - REDO, obj.to_mesh(), append, etc) Not sure exactly but I wouldn't bet on it. However wouldn't this be a good test case for the new GIZMOs introduced in 4.3 ?

@Gorgious Yes, but the very algorithm described by OP relies on the two first indices of each mesh island having a different meaning than the third index. Or differently: the first edge of mesh island has a different meaning than than the optional second. You could change the algorithm and mark one edge e.g. sharp but then the tool is harder to use. As for gizmos: unfortunately this problem shows the limitations of gizmos: you can't have a dynamic number of gizmos, and there's no slick way to move a gizmo based on e.g. mouse cursor position to the nearest vertex.

Wow! This was Awesome!! You resolved nearly all of my issues. Thanks for clearing up the whole thing about indices. I guess I confused myself between mesh islands and connected points.
